# How to search Date in SQL Server 2012 over two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
Event (eventID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)
```

- `StartDateTime` is `datetime` datatype
- `EndDateTime` is `datetime` datatype

Now sample data could be like so:

```
EventID   StartDateTime             EndDateTime
-----------------------------------------------------------
   1      2014-02-21 00:00:00.000   2014-02-23 23:59:59.000
   2      2014-02-22 00:00:00.000   2014-02-24 23:59:59.000
```

I want to search what events are happening at `2014-02-23 00:00:00.000`

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    Event
WHERE
    (StartDateTime <= '2/23/2013 00:00:00 AM')
    OR (EndDateTime >= '2/23/2013 00:00:00 AM')
```

I have tried the above code but it doesn't return correct result.

Am I missing something? Can you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: select * from event where '2/23/2013 00:00:00 AM' between startdatime and enddatetime don't do it correctly? You would perhaps have to add a little to the enddate cause if i remember well it's not inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query

```
SELECT * FROM Event
     WHERE '2014-02-23 00:00:00.000' BETWEEN StartDateTime and EndDateTime
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `OR`, you want `AND`. You want events that started before or on the date you specified, *and* that end after the date you specified:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    Event
WHERE
    StartDateTime <= '20130223'
    AND
    EndDateTime > '20130223'
```

Also, I'd seriously recommend that you start storing these date ranges as a semi-open interval, with an *exclusive* end date, if the time portion is important. It's a lot easier to compute exclusive end points, that read more cleanly:

```
INSERT INTO Event(EventID,StartDateTime,EndDateTime) values
(1,'2014-02-21T00:00:00.000','2014-02-24T00:00:00.000'),
(2,'2014-02-22T00:00:00.000','2014-02-25T00:00:00.000')
```

Which has the advantage that it's not (arbitrarily) excluding the last minute of the day, as your current ranges do.

Comment: how to convert ' 2014-02-21 00:00:00.000' to  20140221  in sql server 2012?

Answer (score 1):

did you try BETWEEN?

```
DECLARE @EventTime DATETIME
SET @EventTime = '20140223 00:00:00'

SELECT * 
FROM EVENT
WHERE @EventTime BETWEEN StartDateTime AND EndDateTime
```

Comment: doesn't return anything!

Comment: try to set @EventTime = '20130223 00:00:00'

Comment: Your Sampledata contains entries for 2014... try to set @EventTime = '20140223 00:00:00' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Between](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx&ei=KqoFU_jcOM36iQf9lIGoBQ&usg=AFQjCNFHvxNZ3KjUm9idEB4GAQ-2wLVloA&sig2=tBTuNi1yF5l9QWuhk7uylw&bvm=bv.61725948,d.aGc) operator in WHERE clause . It specifies a range to test.

- Note **BETWEEN** operator is inclusive of boundary cases.

  **BETWEEN** returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.